# .net core - PInvoke C shared library function which depends on another shared library

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, shared-libraries, .net-core, pinvoke

I wrote some wrapper code for an existing library ([wiringPi](http://wiringpi.com/)) to read a temperature sensor but ended up with an error while consuming this library.

My wrapper lib looks like:

### mylib.h

```c
#ifndef mylib_h__
#define mylib_h__
extern void read_sensor();
#endif
```

### mylib.c

```c
#include "mylib.h"
#include <wiringPi.h> 

void read_sensor() {
    //here is the first call on the wiringPi lib
    if (wiringPiSetup() == -1)
        exit(1);

    ...
}
```

then i use gcc to compile my library:

```sh
gcc -Wall -Werror -fPIC -c mylib.c
gcc -shared -o libmylib.so mylib.o -lwiringPi
cp libmylib.so /usr/lib/
```

**Hint:** In case of a normal C program consumption of this library everything works fine.

Now there‘s my C# program which use `PInvoke` to call `read_sensor()` from this library:

### Program.cs

```cs
class Program 
{
    [DllImport("wiringPi")]
    static extern int wiringPiSetup();

    [DllImport("mylib")]
    static extern void read_sensor();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        wiringPiSetup();
        read_sensor();
    }
}
```

This program is compiled with the following arguments:

```
dontet publish -r linux-arm
```

and copied to my Raspberry-Pi.

Now i execute this C# program and the following error is thrown:

> ./my-program-name: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libmylib.so: undefined symbol: wiringPiSetup

What‘s going wrong here?

My first thought was, my program didn‘t know the wiringPi library. So i added an export for this dll and called `wiringPiSetup()` for testing. Same result with or without this statement.

I added also a test function without the wiringPi dependency into my custom library. This is called fine by C#.

Did i mess something up at linking time?

**Edit:**

The command `ldd /usr/lib/libmylib.so` gives this output:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x7efad000)
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so (0x76f73000)
libwiringPi.so => /usr/local/lib/libwiringPi.so (0x76f40000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 (0x76dff000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so.6 (0x76d84000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0 (0x76d5c000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/librt.so.1 (0x76d45000)
libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcrypt.so.1 (0x76d05000)
/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0x54abc000)
```

Comment: Didn't you ask this already?

Comment: Note the usage of LD_DEBUG in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27054737/how-to-fix-symbol-lookup-error-undefined-symbol-errors-in-a-cluster-environment) to get more troubleshooting info.

Comment: What does `ldd /usr/lib/libmylib.so` say? Does it include a `libwiringPi.so`?

Comment: I added the output to my question.

Comment: Name decoration? http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_data/article.php/c4217/Calling-Unmanaged-Code-Part-1--simple-DLLImport.htm  Would something like this work: [DllImport("TestDll.dll", EntryPoint="myproc", 
   ExactSpelling=false,CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]

Comment: @AdamBenson yea, that actually worked. Could you explain this in an answer? I will accept it.

Comment: @senz - Glad it helped :-) I've added the answer - if you think it needs anything more let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It comes down to name decoration. The C++ compiler doesn't just put the name of a function in the object file - it adds information to the name according to the function's definition (most notably its parameters).

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56h2zst2.aspx

> Functions, data, and objects in C and C++ programs are represented
>   internally by their decorated names. A decorated name is an encoded
>   string created by the compiler during compilation of an object, data,
>   or function definition. It records calling conventions, types,
>   function parameters and other information together with the name. This
>   name decoration, also known as name mangling, helps the linker find
>   the correct functions and objects when linking an executable.

**But** Compiled C code does not do this - name decorating (or name mangling) came in with C++.

So, you have to tell C# "this function's name is not decorated."

To do that use an attribute like this:

```
[DllImport("TestDll.dll", EntryPoint="myproc", ExactSpelling=false,CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdec‌​l)]
```

It's the "CallingConvention" bit that says "the function is a C function."

"Cdecl" means "C declaration", if I remember right.

More information can be found at: http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_data/article.php/c4217/Calling-Unmanaged-Code-Part-1--simple-DLLImport.htm